# iOS navigate to other view on didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have one view with table view and on touch on row I want to navigate to other view.
Everything is ok, but buttons, labels and others didnt render on view.

[image: Storyboard]

For navigation to other view I use this code:

```
GenderViewController *myController = [[GenderViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:myController animated:YES];
[myController release];
```

Where can be problem please?

Thank you!

Comment: your are using storyborad try using prepareforseague .please crosscheck with storyboard tutorials

Comment: I see no error in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use storyboards, so use a segue or an identifier for your viewController.

```
GenderViewController *myController = [[GenderViewController alloc] initWithNibName: nil bundle:nil];
```

wouldn't help much, since you don't provide a nib name (I think you can't use this with storyboard since you have no nib name, but am not 100% sure).

Set an identifier of your viewController in Interface Builder and instantiate it like this:

```
GenderViewController *myController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"yourIdentifier"];
```

Comment: Okey, I setted Storyboard ID to "GenderView" and updated code to use instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier. But I will get error: `2013-02-13 11:56:29.506 AppName[3676:c07] -[NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint isViewLoaded]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9344350
2013-02-13 11:56:29.507 AppName[3676:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint isViewLoaded]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9344350'`

Comment: Okay, I fix that. I deleted releasing the myController line and now everything works ok. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have `GenderViewController` nib file. But while you allocating the class `GenderViewController`, you are creating it with passing `nil`.